# Display time in 24 hours

Tags: php

I am displaying current server time using php date function like:

```
 date("H:i:s");
```

but it displays time 12-hours on my local machine.

please help me.

Comment: did you check this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I am facing a problem that current time of my machine is 4:28 pm. date("h:i:s A") displays time like 04:12:48 AM . when I checked it using date("H:i:s"), then it again displays 04:12:48.

Comment: A case of RTFM I think. Your machine time has nothing to do with it. It's the time on the server that PHP is running on.

Comment: If date("H:i:s"); shows you the time of your local machine, perhaps you are running your script in your local machine. date() function shows the time of the machine on which the script is running.

Comment: Dear @BenM yes  I want to get php server time which should be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');` before calling `date()`.

I don't know why it's called `Asia/Calcutta`? Perhaps because `Allahabad` is closer to `Calcutta/Kolkata` than the capital city.

Edit: for next question in comment:

The reason you're getting `UTC` time is default timezone is set to `UTC` in php.ini` like

`date.timezone = UTC` check it. Change it accordingly to get desired effect.

Comment: Get correct time using this on my local machine. But when I upload the script on hosting sever, then I don't the time zone of server. Then How it would be possible to display correct time

Comment: default timezone will be set in `php.ini` with param `date.timezone = UTC` check it. It has to be updated based on installation location.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
echo date("H:i:s", time());
```

or try with this

```
echo date('G:i:s',time());
```

it will work